# Certificates between services in a single machine

Tags: web-application, certificates, client

I'd like to know if it's possible to protect communications between a heavy client on a machine and a remote server accessible by a web interface on this machine using certificates. Or the only way is to set a certificate for the whole client machine ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? If the machine or user is compromised, encryption won't help. Also, what type of certificates  do you mean?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve. But normal HTTPS already does the encryption and certificates are involved in authenticating the server application. Optionally also a certificate can be used to authenticate the client application (mutual TLS). What else do you need?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I'd like to know if it's possible to encrypt and authenticate communications inside the workstation between the heavy client and the Web browser launched by the heavy client to interact with the remote server.

Comment: Would it be possible to set certificate for the heavy client and another one for the web browser locally at the machine?